# clang-format align postfix types in declarations

Tags: typescript, formatting, clang-format

Is there any way to align postfix types using clang-format?

I have the below options set but it seems to have no effect on declarations in typescript (postfix types)

From the [Clang 6 documentation](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html):

> **AlignConsecutiveAssignments** (`bool`)
>   If `true`, aligns consecutive
>   assignments.
>
> This will align the assignment operators of consecutive lines. This
>   will result in formattings like
>
> ```
> int aaaa = 12;
> int b    = 23;
> int ccc  = 23;
> ```
>
> **AlignConsecutiveDeclarations** (`bool`)
>   If `true`, aligns consecutive
>   declarations.
>
> This will align the declaration names of consecutive lines. This will
>   result in formattings like
>
> ```
> int         aaaa = 12;
> float       b = 23;
> std::string ccc = 23;
> ```

I want something like this:

```
const aaaa: int = 12;
const b:    int = 23;
const ccc:  int = 23;
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to be possible as of version 10.0.